# Do I need to install Zchaff before using NuXMV to do verification by BMC

Tags: formal-verification, model-checking, nuxmv

I just install NuXMV and want to use it to do Bounded Model Checking. But in user-mannual, the writer says NuXMV doesn't contain Zchaff of minisat. So do i need to install them before starting the work

I use "*msat_check_ltlspec_bmc*" to verify a simple specification and it can work, and this make me more confused.Here is my simple model.[the simple smv model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XOl9.png)
Here is the result.[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okU05.png)